# How to write KDB query output to a text file

Tags: kdb, q

```
filePath:hsym `$("/c/d/f/a.txt");
.co.fileHandle: hopen filePath;
x:select a,c from tab
neg[.co.fileHandle]  x
```

neg[.co.fileHandle]  x >> is throwing type: Mismatched types errors

I am aware that I can directly save it as `:/c/d/f/x.txt. But, after writing query output to a.txt I want to add output of other queries also.

Comment: Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: It's unclear in the question what format you want. CSV? JSON? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That only allows for a string or lists of strings to be appended to the file. Can use `.Q.s` to convert your table to strings.

```
q)neg[.co.fileHandle] .Q.s x
```

Can then verify the file contains the output

```
> cat /c/d/f/a.txt
a c
---
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas. Its meeting my pupose.